# How to show one result and to remove the duplicate category

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to show only one result using the following query:

```
<?php
foreach($list as $row=>$item){
?>     

    <li>

        <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') == 1) : ?>
            <a class="<?php echo $item->category_title; ?>" href="#">
              <?php echo $item->category_title; ?>
            </a>

        <?php
            else:
            echo $item->category_title;
            endif;
        ?> 

    </li>              
<?php }?>
```

The result was:

```
All
Onesies
Leggings
Swimsuits
Onesies
Leggings
Swimsuits
Onesies
Leggings
Swimsuits
Leggings
Onesies
Swimsuits
Onesies
Onesies
```

My question is, I would like to know how to remove a duplicate category.

I have resolved this issue with jquery.

Example after the foreach this is the output.

```
<ul class="filter">
<li><a href="#">Same Title </a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Different Title </a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Different Title </a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Different Title </a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Same Title </a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Same Title </a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Same Title </a> </li>
</ul>
```

This is the solution

```
var seen='';$('ul.filter li').each(function(){
    var see=$(this).text();
    if(seen.match(see)){
        $(this).remove();}
    else{
        seen=seen+$(this).text();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

One quick trick is to just store them into a 2 dimensional array.  Just do the following instead of echo'ing out the item the moment you have it:

```
$clothes[$item->category_title] = 0;
```

An entry is created and when you hit a duplicate it just recreates an entry.  Now you can

```
foreach ( $clothes as $item => $count )
{
    echo $item;
}
```

As an added tidbit, you could even increment the value, instead of setting it to 0, in case you need to know how many times the item appears in the list

Comment: I renamed it from $junk to $count, so that the asker would see what I was talking about in regards to added functionality

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Was funny tho. Creating variables' name is also uneasy task for programmers.

Comment: When I have variables that are useless like that, I really do name them $junk in my code, just so that it's purpose is obvious.

Comment: Sorry but this solution not work. I resolve this problem with jquery.